# How can a R object be a typeof list and also return is.data.frame true?

Tags: r

I have an R object named xCategories

```
> xCategories

    code frequency percentage
1      1        75 12.3762376
2      1        75 12.3762376
3      1        75 12.3762376
4      1        75 12.3762376
5      1        75 12.3762376
6      2         0  0.0000000
7      2         0  0.0000000
8      2         0  0.0000000
9      3         8  1.3201320
10     3         8  1.3201320
11     3         8  1.3201320
12     3         8  1.3201320
```

when I check what type of object it is the answer is list

```
> typeof(xCategories)
[1] "list"
```

when I check if the object is a data frame ... the answer is true

```
> is.data.frame(xCategories)
[1] TRUE
```

How can a R object be a typeof list and also return is.data.frame true?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Data-frames

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `data.frame` is "class", but has "mode" `list`. You possibly need to understand the difference between `class` and `mode`. Note, `typeof` returns `mode` or `storage.mode`. These documentation will help you `?class`, `?mode`, `?typeof`.